# What should [vectors] refer to?

Tags: discussion, tags

Vectors can refer to either expandable array data structures of elements, for example `std::vector`, or to a SIMD vector type, which is typically fixed-sized and permits one instruction to act on all of the values at once.

What should [vectors](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vectors) refer to? Ambiguous tags are [frowned upon](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/171). My vote is using [vectors](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vectors) for the **former** and [simd](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simd) and/or a new [simd-vector](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simd-vector) or similar tag for the latter. Any objections or thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

## Delete it

[As I mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63595165#63595165), questions should either be tagged [simd](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simd) or [arrays](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrays).

Comment: It's probably worth also noting that avoiding a [tag:vector] tag also avoids confusion with native support for mathematical vectors.

Answer (score 2):

### [vector](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector) should be for mathematical vectors

This is the only sense of "vector" that isn't more clearly expressed in a different way. There might not yet be any relevant questions for that concept, but I don't see a reason to outlaw it preemptively. I can easily imagine someone wanting to design a programming language that has native support for a data type that behaves like a mathematical vector, not to mention that language's standard library.

### [simd](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simd) is good enough for SIMD stuff

Because really, what *other* things do you use in SIMD besides what it calls "vectors"?

### [dynamic-array](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-array) is the clearest term for the other thing

Other languages/ecosystems refer to this concept as "vector" (as noted) or "list"; but these terms are ambiguous. You already noticed the problem with "vector"; "list" can also mean a linked list (and often does). By contrast, "array" can't realistically mean anything that *isn't* a sequence of "real" (i.e., not determined on the fly) values that are actually stored sequentially in memory (although they might be indirected), offering random access.

However, "array" by itself carries a strong connotation of pre-sized storage without any book-keeping information for the size (as in C, for example). I propose to use [array](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) to mean such an array of a fixed size; and [dynamic-array](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-array) to mean what Python calls a list, C++ calls a vector, etc.